# Accessing a object in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I followed the simple tutorial here: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/dataGridview-DataReader.aspx
to create a datagridview filled with objects.

How do I access the objects in the DGV? 
I tried (mydgv.CurrentRow.index as Tool).id, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DataBoundItem` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx):

```
var row = (Tool)mydgv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access them in the ItemDataBound event of the datagridview.
You can cast the e.Item.DataItem to you class.